# Change the sequens of columns in datatable with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a Datatable with the columns

```
Name|Age|Job
```

I query that Datatable with Linq and do some manipulations.

```
Dim query = From row in dt.AsEnumerable.where(...)
```

The returned object is a datatable that I need for further procedures.
But now I have to change the column sequence to

```
Age|Name|Job
```

and do not know how to do that. 
I tried:

```
Dim query1 = From column In query
Select column.Age, column.Name, column.Job
```

But query1 is not a Datatable object anymore. Could anyone help me get the resorting of the columns done that I still have a datatable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataColumn.SetOrdinal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to reorder columns. Assuming that `query` is a datatable with columns `Name|Age|Job`, the following will reorder the columns to `Age|Name|Job` :

```
query.Columns("Age").SetOrdinal(0)
query.Columns("Name").SetOrdinal(1)
```